# Map Object with String array

Tags: gwt, dictionary

```
//code inside servlet

Map<String,Object> m1=new HashMap<String,Object>();
String s1[]={"abc","abbc"};
m1.put("no",s1);
```

I'm getting this Exception while retriving the value String array from map

```
  SEVERE: WebModule[/testingapp]Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
  com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeWithCustomSerializer(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:760)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:723)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:612)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:152)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:534)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:609)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForSuccess(RPC.java:467)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:564)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:188)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:224)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeWithCustomSerializer(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:742)
        ... 37 more
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type '[Ljava.lang.String;' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = [Ljava.lang.String;@1f54e49
        at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:610)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:129)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.Map_CustomFieldSerializerBase.serialize(Map_CustomFieldSerializerBase.java:50)
        at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.core.java.util.HashMap_CustomFieldSerializer.serialize(HashMap_CustomFieldSerializer.java:36)
        ... 42 more
```

help me to solve this exception

Answer (score 0):

It look's like you are trying to send a map with the data type `Object` via RPC, which doesn't work. See https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication#DevGuideSerializableTypes. One reason is that GWT needs to generate support for all children in the client side code, as these might be send, which in case of `Object` would be everything...